# How to program ATmega4809 from Raspbeery GPIO

Tags: spi, avrdude, raspberrypi

From this [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/program-an-avr-or-arduino-using-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins)  I'm able to nicely program an ATmega328 using SPI raspberry GPIO pins. However, when I try the same steps with  ATmega4809, `avrdude` seems not having instructions and outputs the following:

```
program enable instruction not defined for part "ATmega4809"
```

So, how do I program ATmega4809 chip from Raspberry?

Answer (score 1):

The ATMega4809 uses UPDI (Unified Programming and Debugging Interface) for programming, not ICSP like the older ATMega328P. You need a UPDI programmer.

There is a project [jtag2updi](https://github.com/ElTangas/jtag2updi) which you can run on an Uno that turns it into a JTAG to UPDI adaptor which is then compatible with `avrdude -c jtag2updi ...`.

Comment: But in that case, why does it have MOSI, MISO and SCK pins? 
Also, I'm doing some experiments with Arduino Nano Every, which does not have UPDI pin available.

Comment: Because MOSI, MISO and SCK are SPI, not ICSP. It just so happens that on the ATMega328P those pins perform two functions: SPI *and* ICSP. But the two are not related in any way whatsoever.